# How to Sort an NSArray of UIColor Objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, sorting, uicolor

I wrote a class that has a property of type UIColor called color. How can I sort an NSArray containing a handful of instances of my class by the color property? I have tried the code below but get an error: [UICachedDeviceRGBColor compare:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance. What is the best way to sort UIColor objects?

```
NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]initWithKey:@"color" ascending:YES];
array = (NSMutableArray*)[array sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[sort]];
```

Comment: hmm, is red < green or green < red? seriously, how do you think it should be sorted?

Comment: To use the code you posted you would need to create your own category on the `UIColor` class and implement the `compare:` method to compare the two `UIColor` objects. So the next question is - what does it mean to sort two colors?

Comment: mathematically speaking: a sane ordering of colors would imply having a continuous function from the 3-dimensional RGB-colorspace to some real intervall. you can prove easily that such a function does not exist.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sort Colors (Objective-C)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8585037/sort-colors-objective-c)

Comment: Your question has an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8585037/sort-colors-objective-c

Comment: @Michael ROY G BIV. duh XD

Comment: @68cherries and... in English?

Comment: I'm just trying to find duplicate colors, so the method used to sort them doesn't really matter. No need to get all sassy @Michael :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a comparator to return wether one color is greater than the other.

```
NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]initWithKey:@"color" ascending:YES comparator:^(id obj1, id obj2) {

    if (do some math to determine which color is the bestest) {
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedAscending;
    }else{
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending;
    }

}];
```